# Javascript/CSS/HTML mouseover show remote page with no clickable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section of a div container text that I'm trying to 'preview' another page, or at least show it when the mouse is over specific text - I don't want the actual text to be clickable since I need it to remain on the 'main' page

I've messed around using some custom CSS's to 'preview' data, locally, and provide a remote img src, but I cannot seem to find any examples to do this for a page.

Comment: Found something I can use. http://qtip2.com/demos

Answer (score 0):

You can get thumbnails of those pages that you want to show and when they hover that text you can show them that thumbnails. Tt is kind of tricking user since they are not actually seeing the page.

Comment: I have to use an iframe - Found that out the hard way it seems.